# How can I use the .findall() function for a excel file iterating through all rows of a column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a big excel sheet with information about different companies altogether in a single cell for each company and my goal is to separate this into different columns following patterns to **scrape** the info from the first column. The original data looks like this:

[image]

My goal is to achieve a dataframe like this:

[image]

I have created the following code to use the patterns Mr., Affiliation:, E-mail:, and Mobile because they are repeated in every single row the same way. However, I don't know how to use the findall() function to scrape all the info I want from each row of the desired column.

```
import openpyxl
import re
import sys  
import pandas as pd
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/ap/info1.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Companies')
w={'Name': [],'Affiliation': [], 'Email':[]}
for row in ws.iter_rows('C{}:C{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
    for cells in row:
        a=re.findall(r'Mr.(.*?)Affiliation:',aa, re.DOTALL)
        a1="".join(a).replace('\n',' ')
        b=re.findall(r'Affiliation:(.*?)E-mail',aa,re.DOTALL)
        b1="".join(b).replace('\n',' ')
        c=re.findall(r'E-mail(.*?)Mobile',aa,re.DOTALL)
        c1="".join(c).replace('\n',' ')
        w['Name'].append(q1)
        w['Affiliation'].append(r1)
        w['Email'].append(s1)
        print cell.value
        
df=pd.DataFrame(data=w)
df.to_excel(r'/Users/ap/info2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with this, which just replaces the 'E-mail:...' with a delimiter and then splits and assigns to the right column

```
df['Name'] = np.nan
df['Affiliation'] = np.nan
df['Email'] = np.nan
df['Mobile'] = np.nan

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    full_value = df['Companies'].loc[i]
    full_value = full_value.replace('Affiliation:', ';').replace('E-mail:', ';').replace('Mobile:', ';')
    full_value = full_value.split(';')
    df['Name'].loc[i] = full_value[0]
    df['Affiliation'].loc[i] = full_value[1]
    df['Email'].loc[i] = full_value[2]
    df['Mobile'].loc[i] = full_value[3]

del df['Companies']
print(df)
```